# Instantiate scalar of custom structured dtype

Tags: python, numpy, scalar

I have defined a custom dtype. For example:

```
vec = np.dtype([('x', float), ('y', float), ('z', float)])
quat = np.dtype([('w', float), ('v', vec)])
```

Now I want to make a scalar quaternion:

```
quat((1.0, (0.0, 0.0, 0.0)))
```

I would expect that if anything, my tuple syntax is unacceptable. However, instead, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: 'numpy.dtype' object is not callable
```

The [relevant portion](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.scalars.html#defining-new-types) of the [documentation on scalars](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.scalars.html) implies that it is possible to have a scalar of a structured type built like this in numpy.

**How do instantiate a `quat` scalar? Is it even possible?**

By the way, I've played with the following workaround:

```
np.array([(1.0, (0.0, 0.0, 0.0))], dtype=quat)
```

This does not produce an actual scalar (although it honestly works well enough for my purposes, making the question mostly theoretical). Calling `item` on the result returns a `tuple`, not a scalar `quat` object.

Comment: While `int` and `np.float32` can act both as `dtype` and functions to create a numpy scalar, I don't think a `np.dtype` instance can do that.  It doesn't have a `__call__` method (check that).

Comment: A compound dtype creates a `np.void` object.  (or for `recarray` a `np.record`)

Comment: @hpaulj. I totally agree. But there seems to be *some* way implied in the docs. I figure if anyone knows, it'll be you, Divakar or so.

Comment: @hpaulj. So I tried to do `quat.type(pack('dddd', 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0))`. It's probably a step in the right direction, but not exactly helpful in its raw form

Comment: @hpaulj. Got it: `quat.type(pack('dddd', 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)).view(quat)`

Comment: @hpaulj. I've posted an answer, but hoping you can find a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `item` on your array produced a tuple because `item` is specifically designed to convert NumPy types to Python types. Indexing the array produces a NumPy scalar of type `numpy.void`:

```
scalar = np.array([(1.0, (0.0, 0.0, 0.0))], dtype=quat)[0]
```

Comment: This is indeed much cleaner than my version. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is based on the discussion in the comments. It's more painful than it needs to be, since there is unlikely to be a usecase for a custom scalar that can't be solved more handily with a 1-element array.

The type of `quat` is `np.void`:

```
>>> quat.type
numpy.void
```

Since this is a generic catchall for custom types, it has to be instantiated with a bytes-like object:

```
>>> from struct import pack
>>> q = quat.type(pack('dddd', 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0))
>>> q
void(b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xF0\x3F\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00')
```

And of course, since it is a generic catch-all, you need to tell it how to interpret itself. Fortunately, scalars also have a `view` method:

```
>>> q = q.view(quat)
>>> q
(1., (0., 0., 0.))
>>> q.dtype
dtype([('w', '<f8'), ('v', [('x', '<f8'), ('y', '<f8'), ('z', '<f8')])])
```

**TL;DR**

```
q = np.void(pack('dddd', 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)).view(quat)
```