# How to use isinstance() on a numpy structured array custom type

Tags: python, numpy

In the below example I create a custom type, then an array of elements of this type and then I test the first element of this array against this type with `isinstance()`, but I get an Error.

```
import numpy as np

# Here I define a simple type with two fields
my_type_simple = np.dtype([('field_1', int), ('field_2', float)])
# An array using the above type
my_var_simple_1 = np.array([(1, 1), (2, 2)], dtype=my_type_simple)
# For a check, should print [(1, 1.) (2, 2.)]
print(my_var_simple_1)
# For a check, should print True
print(isinstance(my_var_simple_1, np.ndarray))
# The below prints numpy.void - how can I find out that in fact it is 'my_type_simple' ?
print(type(my_var_simple_1[0]))
# The below prints True, at least
print(isinstance(my_var_simple_1[0], type(my_var_simple_1[0])))
# But the below raises an Error: TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a type or tuple of types
print(isinstance(my_var_simple_1[0], my_type_simple))
```

Therefore the question is: how can I test to find out that the `type` of `my_var_simple_1[0]` is in fact `my_simple_type`? Is that at all possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try that, see if it suits your needs:

```
my_var_simple_1[0].dtype == my_type_simple
```

Comment: Damn, that was easy, why did I fix on `isinstance()`? Here the only caveat is that if I deal with a list, it won't have the `dtype` field, but that can be easily worked around. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Maciek. What would you put in a list that's analogous to an instance of a numpy dtype?

Comment: @MadPhysicist sorry, I don't understand the question.

Comment: @Maciek. You say "Here the only caveat is that if I deal with a ...". What does that mean? How is that relevant? How do you have structured numpy dtypes in a list? The whole question seems very specific to numpy arrays

Comment: @MadPhysicist, well, it is just that numpy methods tend to work with ndarrays, but also iterables, such as lists, thus I wanted my methods to be generic too.

Comment: @Maciek. Numpy methods don't work work most iterates or even sequences except lists and tuples. They do so by calling `np.array`, `np.asarray`, `np.asanyarray`, or similar   on the list. I suggest you do the same. Structured dtypes don't mean anything in a list unless the list already contains arrays.

Comment: @Maciek. I recently had a question that's related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/63855789/2988730. Basically, structured dtype scalars are of type `np.void`, which is related to `bytes`. You can't represent then meaningfully without wrapping in an array.

Answer (score 1):

```
In [7]: my_type_simple = np.dtype([('field_1', int), ('field_2', float)])
   ...: # An array using the above type
   ...: my_var_simple_1 = np.array([(1, 1), (2, 2)], dtype=my_type_simple)
```

The `dtype` command creates an `dtype` object, an instance of that class.  It doesn't subclass `dtype`.

```
In [8]: type(my_type_simple)
Out[8]: numpy.dtype
```

The object created with `np.array` is a numpy array, `ndarray`.  That's true regardless of the `dtype`.

```
In [11]: type(my_var_simple_1)
Out[11]: numpy.ndarray
```

For compound dtypes the type of an element is `void`.  The `type` for each of your two fields is `np.int64` and `np.float64`, but the combination is `np.void`.

```
In [12]: type(my_var_simple_1[0])
Out[12]: numpy.void
```

But we can access the `dtype` of the array or its element, and test that:

```
In [13]: my_var_simple_1.dtype
Out[13]: dtype([('field_1', '<i8'), ('field_2', '<f8')])
In [16]: my_var_simple_1[0].dtype
Out[16]: dtype([('field_1', '<i8'), ('field_2', '<f8')])
```

While `type` or `isinstance` can be useful in checking whether an object is `ndarray` as opposed to `list` or something else, the `dtype` is more useful when checking the properties of the array itself.  (asking for `alist.dtype` will raise an error, since lists don't have such an attribute.)  (Object dtype arrays are more like lists.)

Comment: Thanks, in fact I realized all these I think. The fact that the structured type is `np.void` disallowed me to test various types. I could print to screen `dtype([('field_1', '<i8'), ('field_2', '<f8')])` but somehow I got fixed on using `isinstance()` instead of using the `==` operator in the manner suggested in he accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a custom `numpy dtype`. `isinstance` does not apply to the contents of an ndarray. For more info read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40312013/check-type-within-numpy-array).
For your problem you can do:

```
type(my_var_simple_1[0].item())
```

or like [Or Y](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14053345/or-y) mentioned:

```
my_var_simple_1[0].dtype
```

Comment: Yeah, this I already thought about, but would need to specially create a data element just to perform testing. Thanks for the link, I did not find that question when looking for relevant discussion earlier on.